# Heroku app breaks when adding Amazon Simple Storage Service (aws-s3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, heroku

My app works on Heroku until I add "gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'" to the gemfile.  (I've also tried it with only the first part).
As soon as I add this and try to "heroku rake db:migrate"  I get this error

"rake aborted!
no such file to load -- rails/all
/app/Rakefile:4"

It works fine with aws s3 on my local server, and it works fine on heroku up until I change the gemfile.

Any ideas?

*edit*
Here is the whole Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'

gem 'devise'

gem 'omniauth'

gem 'nifty-generators'

gem 'paperclip'

gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'

gem 'aws-s3'


group :development, :test do

  gem 'rspec-rails'

  gem 'annotate-models'

end
```

*/edit*

Comment: I and many others use aws-s3 on Heroku with no problem - can we see the whole of your gemfile

Answer (score 0):

This is going to sound vague but i remember something about needing to specify the version of aws-s3 that i was using in order to get S3 to work properly on one of my Heroku apps. It might be worth trying:

```
config.gem "aws-s3", :version => ">= 0.6.2", :lib => "aws/s3"
```

Don't forget to:

```
bundle update
```

after changing your gemfile.

Sorry, been trying to rack my brain as to where i read this so as to back it up, worth a try though.